# Encoding 20MB flv video into mp4 aac using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, encode, wowza

I have make a shell script for encoding flv video to mp4 video:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /destination/filename -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -vf "movie=/img/logo.png [watermark];[in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" /destination/filename.mp4 2>&1')
```

I have issue while large size flv files, then it could not encode. In the case of 5 flv files with each 20MB could not encode. (I am trying to encode these 1 by one)

Is there any fault in my script?

Comment: Does it work as expected if you run `ffmpeg` manually?

Comment: What's the Output of ffmpeg?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yea its working if i run manually

Comment: @miindlek output is mp4

Comment: @Pus ffmpeg prints out an error Message if it fails. I'm interested in that output.

Comment: @miindlek plesae check the path and this will be the correct, in the ffmpeg version and library it will effect.